# Why SWT List fills all composite?

Tags: java, layout, swt

Hi I have a problem with the layouts in SWT, I want to create an application with 4 equal sized lists. When the lists are empty, each looks good, but when I will fulfill one of the lists with data that covers the entire composite.

[image: Empty Lists]

and lists with data:

[image]

I know that it by wrong layout, so I'll show you some source:

```
shlPirotechnikafcwnxrap.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

......

Composite mainComposite = new Composite(shlPirotechnikafcwnxrap,
                SWT.NONE);
        mainComposite.setLayout(new FormLayout());

......

    Composite rightCenterComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
        rightCenterComposite.setLayoutData(new FormData());
        rightCenterComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        rightCenterComposite.setLayoutData(GUIHelper.getFormData(5, 100, 30, 100));

        TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(rightCenterComposite, SWT.NONE);
        tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        /**
         * TAB ITEM
         */
        TabItem tbtmSql = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        tbtmSql.setText("SQL");

        /**
         * Composite inside TabItem
         */
        Composite sqlTabComposite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout gl_sqlTabComposite = new GridLayout();
        gl_sqlTabComposite.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
        gl_sqlTabComposite.numColumns = 2;
        sqlTabComposite.setLayout(gl_sqlTabComposite);
        sqlTabComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        tbtmSql.setControl(sqlTabComposite);

        Group grpSowaKluczoweSql = new Group(sqlTabComposite, SWT.NONE);
        grpSowaKluczoweSql.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        grpSowaKluczoweSql.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        grpSowaKluczoweSql.setText("S\u0142owa kluczowe i operatory SQL:");

        List listSlowaKluczoweSql = new List(grpSowaKluczoweSql, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        listSlowaKluczoweSql.setLayoutData(new FormData());
        listSlowaKluczoweSql.setLayoutData(GUIHelper.getFormData(0, 100, 0, 100));

        Group grpTabele = new Group(sqlTabComposite, SWT.NONE);
        grpTabele.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        grpTabele.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));
        grpTabele.setText("Nazwy tabel:");

        List listTabele = new List(grpTabele, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        listTabele.setLayoutData(new FormData());
        listTabele.setLayoutData(GUIHelper.getFormData(0, 100, 0, 100));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this: `sqlTabComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));` You are using `FILL` + grab excess space. Try using appropriate layout constants, like `BEGINNING` for horizontal alignment and `TOP` for vertical. Also set `grabExcessVerticalSpace` to false. Check all related places.

Comment: I tried your solution and somewhat works, but I also want to retain the proportions of the components after resizing windows. That is resize components when window resizes and vice versa

Comment: Try to add a resize listener and adjust your controls accordingly?

Comment: Problem solved, I have changed layouts to `FormLayout` with `FormData`. Thank you for your time.